# Oracle Ecommerce where to set shippingCountries

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

When I try to use shippingCountries in the checkout wedget, imports part like:

```
{
     "imports":["shippingCountries","billingCountries"]
}
```

I wonder where I can set the shipping countries I want? Would somebody help me look at this ?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the setting page I finally find the config . And I never want to use this again. It conceals so many things